# Обновление файла python на heroku

Tags: python, heroku

На heroku залит файл .py. Я внес в этот файл некоторые изменения. Как обновить файл на Heroku?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у вас настроен деплой через Github, то необходимо просто сделать `push` в нужную ветку. Если же вы работали с CLI, то из директории вашего приложения надо выполнить `$ git push heroku master`